# Custom Layout update not visible in admin in single store mode

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, magento-admin

So I'm well aware that the Custom Layout Update changed with update 2.3.4 so that you now need to create an XML file.

My Problem..

When **Single Store Mode is switched to YES**,  the file is not visible in the Category admin menu under Design: Custom Layout Update.

Switch **Single Store Mode to NO**, and the file is then able to be selected in Design: Custom Layout Update.

I am using the Olegnax Athlete 2 theme and the theme developer assures me there is nothing wrong with the theme. I'm including two screenshots of the stores config in Single Store mode below.

https://ibb.co/YTFv9pS

https://ibb.co/8jrq5zD

Notice in single store mode the store and store view are blank in the Content:design:configuration.  I believe this is normal in single Store mode.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a related Magento 2 bug report, wherein single store mode is mentioned in the comments: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27942. No solution yet, but hopefully there will be an update.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the indexer for the design config grid?

`./bin/magento indexer:reindex design_config_grid`

Comment: Yes, have tried this, and it doesnt seem to make any change.  The only thing that works is to turn Enable Single Store Mode to NO.   And I dont want to do this unless I absolutely have to.